# Styling the action bar compatibility

Tags: android

I copied this extract directly from the android online documentation [Styling the Action Bar](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html#CustomBackground)

For Android 3.0 and higher only

When supporting Android 3.0 and higher only, you can define the action bar's background like this:

```
res/values/themes.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
    <style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
           parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <!-- ActionBar styles -->
    <style name="MyActionBar"
           parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbar_background</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

My minSdk is 11 and yet I'm receiving compatibility warnings at the parent tag. Why?

Answer (score 0):

`Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar` is only 4.0+, that's why you get the warning. To fix that you can use Holo Light, or change the theme according the the Android version (so you'll have light on Honeycomb and Light with dark actionbar on ICS+).

Comment: are you saying there is an error in the documentation?

Comment: Yes, DarkActionBar is SDK 14+

Comment: To use the darkactionbar on Honeycomb you need [Sherlock Action bar](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) or [appcompact](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html) (you can find some example and guides on Google)